# SCAP Workbench: Scan of 18.04 shows status "notapplicable"

Tags: security

I recently learned about OpenSCAP. Today I wanted to take a closer look, so in installed `scap-workbench` and tried to scan the machine with the provided Ubuntu profiles. I tried VMs with Ubuntu 18.04, 19.04 (not an LTS) and 16.04 (too cumbersome to install). I settled for 18.04, downloaded the latest [release](https://github.com/ComplianceAsCode/content/releases) and extracted the respective 18.04 file, but when I scan the machine it still says **not applicable**.

What is required to have a machine checked against a profile?

I tried to use the program on Fedora and had no issues with the guides suggested for Fedora.

[image]

Comment: Same issue here. Did not have any issue with RHEL or CentOS profile.